# Application won't run when installed in "/opt"

Tags: application-development, quickly, packaging

I've developed a program for the App Developer Showdown, with quickly, in python, and it works as expected when I package and install it normally -in /usr. However when packaged for installation in /opt it doesn't run -and I'm not getting (or can't find) an error message of any sort, as to what the problem might be. I was wondering if someone here has the answer.

The app does require root access -using gksudo- to function.

Application:

- https://launchpad.net/aplomb

Comment: Could you share your solution with how you got quickly to create the share/locale link?

Comment: @user75704 The answer I added below should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `gksudo` stuff in `bin/aplomb` you see the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/aplomb/bin/aplomb", line 48, in <module>
    import aplomb
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/aplomb/aplomb/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from aplomb import AplombWindow
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/aplomb/aplomb/AplombWindow.py", line 23, in <module>
    locale.bindtextdomain('aplomb', '/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/aplomb/share/locale')
NameError: name 'locale' is not defined
```

Comment: That led me to solving my problem, thanks! Only to allow me to find another...

Answer (score 1):

Adding these lines to the necessary files should solve your locale problems.

```
import locale

TEXTDOMAIN = 'yourapp'
LOCALEDIR = '/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/yourapp/share/locale'
#LOCALEDIR = '/usr/yourapp/share/locale'
from locale import gettext as _
locale.bindtextdomain(TEXTDOMAIN, LOCALEDIR)
locale.textdomain(TEXTDOMAIN)
```